# Hash doesn't print in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash:

```
while( my( $key, $value ) = each %sorted_features ){
  print "$key: $value\n";
}
```

but I cannot obtain the correct value for `$value`. It gives me:

```
intron: ARRAY(0x3430440)
source: ARRAY(0x34303b0)
exon: ARRAY(0x34303f8)
sig_peptide: ARRAY(0x33f0a48)
mat_peptide: ARRAY(0x3430008)
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 10):

Your values are array references. You need to do something like

```
while( my( $key, $value ) = each %sorted_features ) {
  print "$key: @$value\n";
}
```

In other words, dereference the reference. If you are unsure what your data looks like, a good idea is to use the `Data::Dumper` module:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%sorted_features;
```

You will see something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'intron' => [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                      ]
        };
```

Where `{` denotes the start of a hash reference, and `[` an array reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your hash values are *array references*. You need to write additional code to display the contents of these arrays, but if you are just debugging then it is probably simpler to use [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) like this

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

print Dumper \%sorted_features;
```

And, by the way, the name `%sorted_features` of your hash worries me. hashes are inherently unsorted, and the order that `each` retrieves the elements is essentially random.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also  `Data::Dumper::Pertidy` which runs the output of Data::Dump through Perltidy.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper::Perltidy;

my $data = [{title=>'This is a test header'},{data_range=>
           [0,0,3,    9]},{format     => 'bold' }];

print Dumper $data;
```

**Prints:**

```
$VAR1 = [
    { 'title'      => 'This is a test header' },
    { 'data_range' => [ 0, 0, 3, 9 ] },
    { 'format'     => 'bold' }
];
```